# How to return an array in UPPAAL?

Tags: uppaal

I am trying to return an integer array in an UPPAAL function.
What is the correct syntax for that?

This code snippet doesn't work:

```
int[] randomTest(int N)
{
    int test[2];
    test[0] = 0;
    test[1] = 1;
    return test;
}
```

Comment: which langugage you are use?

Comment: I use uppaal (http://www.uppaal.org/). It is a academic tool for model checking.

Comment: The array types are not supported as a function return, please use reference parameter. 
1) "int[]" is incomplete type, which decays into a pointer and pointers are not supported, so that's probably not what you want anyway.
2) array types are not implemented because it demands significant temporary storage, it is especially tricky if such function is called from a property/query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Arrays are allowed for clocks, channels, constants and integer variables.

They are defined by appending a size to the variable name,

`e.g. chan c[4]; clock a[2]; int[3,5] u[7];`.

Initialisers are used to initialise integer variables and arrays of integer variables.

For instance, `int i := 2; or int i[3] := {1, 2, 3};`.

Comment: Thanks, but it is not possible to return a integer array in a function? For example 

int i[3] := {1,2,3};
return i;

That's not possible